# Using Different Admob account for Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, adsense

I have a google account associated with  Google Play Store, but for that google account, Adsense is not approved. I didn't find any way to deactivate or cancel the unapproved Adsense account. I want to create a new google account, then Admob and then Adsense account.

How can I use the newly created admob account's ad to my existing  Google Play Store account?

Comment: You cannot have both abmob and adsense accounts for single email

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use different admob account to showing ads in your application

Comment: If I have Google Play Store account named jaimin@gmail.com, and If I have another gmail account named jaimin2@gmail.com for the Admob and Adsence. Where I will get paid ?

Comment: It is compulsory to make same account for Admob, AdSence and Google play store account ?

Comment: for the payment is add your jaimin2@gmail.com account.